# How to make the end date greater than the begin date validation in my application in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

How do I ensure the `end date` is greater than the `begin date` in my application using Delphi?

For example,

If I input my `begin date` as `12/01/2000` and in my end date as `12/01/1999` using TDBEdit how can I prevent the End Date from being before the begin date

I need to raise a `raise.exception.create('your end date is illogical.');`?

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the save button, or before you save the data (you can use the dataset's `BeforePost` event), you can make the check, focus the startdate and show a message and raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StrToDate()` to convert the two strings into `TDateTime` values, then you can use arithmetic operators like `<` to compare those values to each other.